# TLE in case of unsigned

Tags: time, types

I was solving a question on spoj and got TLE when I used unsigned long long while it got accepted when I used long long.

Here is the link to the problem.[Click Here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/BEENUMS/)

Can someone please tell the reason.

Comment: Performance difference is almost negligible in case of signed and unsigned. I don't consider that to be the reason for your TLE. There has to be some kind of other bug. I suggest you share your code.

Comment: Yes there was a bug due to which is was giving TLE. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the possible reason you get a TLE when using `unsigned long long` is because the question mentions that the end of the input is supposed to be a `-1`, so when you try to store a `-1` in an `unsigned long long` it will be stored as a positive number (Something like this http://ideone.com/r4Pvp0). So, your loop for taking the user input never ends because you will never encounter a negative number and hence the TLE.

Something similar to your case ::

```
int main() {
    unsigned int a = -10;
    if(a < 0)
        cout << "Hello";
    else
        cout << "Bye";
    return 0;
}
```

Just using `int a` would print `Hello`, but using `unsigned int` screws it, and the output would be `Bye`. See this :: http://ideone.com/99qq2U

So you got to stick to `long long` if you want to end the user input with a `-1`.